# How to fix '.setFullYear is not a function'

Tags: javascript

I receive an error Uncaught TypeError: thisDay.setFullYear is not a function while attempting to modify the values.

I've attempted debugging in various stages of the code and have confirmed that I am able to access the thisDay variable from within my moveDate function, it just does not allow me to use any date functions on it.

My code I have been fighting with is located at
https://jsfiddle.net/ramseys1990/g9cp42bj/3/

The snippet of the main problem is:

```
function moveDate(selection) {

    switch(selection) {
        case "prevYear":
            thisDay.setFullYear((thisDay.getFullYear() - 1).toInteger);
            putCalendar(thisDay.getMonth(), thisDay.getFullYear() - 1);
            break;
        case "prevMonth":
            thisDay.setMonth(thisDay.getMonth() - 1);
            //putCalendar(thisDay.getMonth() - 1, thisDay.getFullYear());
            break;
        case "nextMonth":
            thisDay.setMonth(thisDay.getMonth() + 1);
            //putCalendar(thisDay.getMonth() + 1, thisDay.getFullYear());
            break;
        case "nextYear":
            thisDay.setFullYear(thisDay.getFullYear() + 1);
            //putCalendar(thisDay.getMonth(), thisDay.getFullYear() + 1);
            break;
        case "today":
            thisDay = new Date();
            //putCalendar(thisDay.getMonth(), thisDay.getFullYear());
            break;
    }
    putCalendar(thisDay.getMonth(), thisDay.getFullYear());
    return;
}
```

My putCalendar function is:

```
function putCalendar(month, year) {


    // Set the date displayed in the calendar 

    thisDay.setMonth = month;
    thisDay.setFullYear = year;
    // Determine the current month
    //var thisMonth = thisDay.getMonth();
    // Determine the current year
    //var thisYear = thisDay.getFullYear();

    // write the calendar to the element with the id 'calendar'
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = createCalendar(thisDay);
}
```

And the top of my code file is currently:

```
"use strict";
var thisDay = new Date();
putCalendar(thisDay.getMonth(), thisDay.getFullYear());
```

I expect it to pass the modified date to my putCalendar function to recreate the calendar for a different year or month.

Comment: In your `putCalendar` you should do `.setMonth(month)` instead of `.setMonth = month`, and the same with the year.

Comment: Jesus, thank you! this solved the whole problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that here

```
putCalendar(thisDay.getMonth(), thisDay.getFullYear());
```

you **call** `getFullYear` and its return value gets passed to `putCalendar`, which is **not a function**.

Then `year`, and `.setFullYear` will get this value, and when you try to call it, it will fail.